# How run a service every minute on a webserver

Tags: linux, service

I don't have much experience running a large scale website, but I'm working on a project that will require a service to run basically non-stop. This service will gather information via an API and because of the amount of data I'm collecting it'll have to run 400 requests every 4 hours or so.

Before I've used cron jobs to run php scripts that perform the functions necessary, but I'm not sure if this is an effective method for handling that number of requests.

What do large websites use in order to issues like this?

The best I can think of is creating a custom application that runs non-stop. Are there any other solutions to this?

I'm going to be using a Linux server, what options do I have and will it require a dedicated server?

Comment: Can you write a script that runs 400 requests and run it every 4 hours?

Comment: In my experience the script takes 1-2s to run for each request so it would be running for 400s or ~13 minutes. I'm not sure if that puts too much strain on the server. On small scale websites I've got into trouble running cron jobs every minute. I get notices that I'm using too many resources. On this project, I'm expecting to upgrade to a dedicated server or VPS, but I'm looking for options that require a minimal amount of resources.

Comment: What would the service do differently? It will do the same work I suppose?

Comment: Yea it's the same job just through different means, because the quantity of work I'm looking at is more massive than anything I've dealt with in the past. I'm mostly curious about the options out there. The two I can come up with is efficient cron job management OR a separate application running non-stop. But I'm wondering what that application would look like. Java? VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Apache style Pre-Forked model, in which you have a supervisor process that forks N number of worker processes, and handles SIGCHLDs etc.  The child processes will connect to a job queue, and block waiting for work to be given to them.

The job queue is usually something like a redis queue, to which you can pump job data.

The completed work is usually fed back through a different queue with the jobid, which is then collected by a separate task and 'some work' is done (saving the results somewhere, passing the results to a different queue to do different work, etc).

See http://python-rq.org/docs/ & http://gearman.org/ as example frameworks.